# Border around UIPopover arrow

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, quartz-core

I have a UIPopover View where I added a 1pt border around to help differentiate between the Popover content and the content underneath.  Does anyone know of a way to continue the border around the arrow?

I've tried adding the border to:

```
self.tableview.layer;

self.view.layer;

self.view.superview.layer;
```

None of them seem to apply to the arrow.

Here's a picture for reference:

[image]

Comment: Did you do this with `popoverBackgroundViewClass` and `UIPopoverBackgroundView`?

Comment: @Wain thanks for the hint....working on it now.

Comment: Well it seems the only way is to use an image, which I was hoping to avoid.  Thanks @Wain for helping out.